# R, LME and Tukey Test produces error after sorting

Tags: r

Below you will find a simplified code snip which is able tp reproduce an error I get:

```
rm(list=ls(all=TRUE))
rawdata <- read.table(file = "test.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",", dec=".", stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
sets <- levels(as.factor(rawdata[,'set']))
index <-  rawdata[,'set']==sets[1]
testdata <- rawdata[index,]

testdata$name <- as.factor(testdata$name)
testdata$name <- factor(testdata$name, as.character(testdata$name))
#### sorting step
sortindex <- with(testdata,order(name))
testdata <- testdata[sortindex,]
####
testdata.lme  <- lme (var~name, random=~1|sample,testdata, method='REML')
testdata.lme.tuk <- summary(glht(testdata.lme, linfct=mcp(name='Tukey')))
```

the error is the following one:

```
Error in glht.matrix(model = list(modelStruct = list(reStruct = list(sample = -10.3240629947066)),  : 
  ‘ncol(linfct)’ is not equal to ‘length(coef(model))’
```

which is not produced if the sorting step is left out. However, I need the sorting in the larger code for other functions and data clean up. Also I want the first variable to represent my control and therefore the intercept.

The same problem occured in some other blogs before but was either not solved, was a data clean up problem or else. Does anyone have an idea?

The data I used here are listed below but I think the error is reproducable as soon as a subset and a sorting step is included:

```
name    var sample  set
423 10.31   1   1
423 10.39   1   1
423 10.86   1   1
421 10.75   1   1
421 10.24   1   1
421 10.27   1   1
424 10.75   1   1
424 10.75   1   1
424 10.75   1   1
423 10.14   2   1
423 10.85   2   1
423 10.48   2   1
425 10.56   1   1
425 10.67   1   1
425 10.17   1   1
426 10.50   1   1
426 10.30   1   1
426 10.29   1   1
423 10.57   3   1
423 10.07   3   1
423 10.01   3   1
428 10.26   1   1
428 10.17   1   1
428 10.72   1   1
429 10.88   1   1
429 10.93   1   1
429 10.63   1   1
423 10.38   4   1
423 10.54   4   1
423 10.25   4   1
432 10.72   1   1
432 10.62   1   1
432 10.14   1   1
434 10.45   1   1
434 10.38   1   1
434 10.41   1   1
435 10.64   1   1
435 10.21   1   1
435 10.21   1   1
423 10.46   5   1
423 10.41   5   1
423 10.13   5   1
501 10.09   1   1
501 10.86   1   1
501 10.05   1   1
503 10.22   1   1
503 10.94   1   1
503 10.38   1   1
423 10.31   1   2
423 10.39   1   2
423 10.86   1   2
421 10.75   1   2
421 10.24   1   2
421 10.27   1   2
424 10.75   1   2
424 10.75   1   2
424 10.75   1   2
423 10.14   2   2
423 10.85   2   2
423 10.48   2   2
425 10.56   1   2
425 10.67   1   2
425 10.17   1   2
426 10.50   1   2
426 10.30   1   2
426 10.29   1   2
423 10.57   3   2
423 10.07   3   2
423 10.01   3   2
428 10.26   1   2
428 10.17   1   2
428 10.72   1   2
429 10.88   1   2
429 10.93   1   2
429 10.63   1   2
423 10.38   4   2
423 10.54   4   2
423 10.25   4   2
432 10.72   1   2
432 10.62   1   2
432 10.14   1   2
434 10.45   1   2
434 10.38   1   2
434 10.41   1   2
435 10.64   1   2
435 10.21   1   2
435 10.21   1   2
423 10.46   5   2
423 10.41   5   2
423 10.13   5   2
501 10.09   1   2
501 10.86   1   2
501 10.05   1   2
503 10.22   1   2
503 10.94   1   2
503 10.38   1   2
```

Comment: When using the `r` tag please use `dput()` to share your data. Hover your pointer over the `r` tag for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you should have to do is to apply `factor()` function to your variable again after a subset or a sorting step:

```
testdata$name <- factor(testdata$name)
```